# Showing that a conjugacy class is completely contained in a normal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

I am working on a homework problem, and although I do not want a solution, I want to ask what is wrong with a certain approach I have.

If $H\subseteq G$ is a normal subgroup in $G$, and $[g]_G$ is the conjugacy class of some $g\in G$, then either $[g]_G \subseteq H$ or $[g]_G\cap H =\varnothing$.

I wanted to show that if there is any element $h\in G$ such that $hgh^{-1}\in H$, then for any other $k\in G$, then $kgk^{-1}\in H$. I assumed that there was some $h\in G$ such that $hgh^{-1}\in H$. Since $H$ normal in $G$ we have that $$h^{-1}Hh = H $$
So we would have \begin{align*}h^{-1}hgh^{-1}h&\in h^{-1}Hh\\
 g&\in h^{-1}Hh\\
g &\in H\end{align*}
However, it is not necessarily true that $g$ is in $H$. So I think this is approach is incorrect. I have found another solution which does lead to this problem, but I would like to know why I reach this conclusion which is not necessarily true.

Comment: if $hgh^{-1} \in H$ and $H$ is normal, that implies that $g \in H$.

Comment: @RolfHoyer  $\;hgh^{-1}\in H\;\;\text{and}\;\;h\in H\implies g\in H\;$  , No need to require $\;H\;$ is normal

Comment: @DonAntonio It is not necessarily the case that $h\in H$, though

Comment: You're using the same symbol $\;h\;$ for two non-necessarily equal element of $\;H\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio I will edit my post to make it clear that $h\in G$ only

Comment: @RolfHoyer That makes a lot of sense, I now realize my misunderstanding. I already assumed that $hgh^{-1}\in H$, so now I can conlcude that $kgk^{-1}\in H$ for any other $k\in G$. I thought I made some wild conclusion that $G=H$ somehow.

Comment: @josh That's true, but I am assuming the symbols used by the OP .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You showed that $[g]_G\cap H\not=\emptyset\implies g\in H$.  But clearly $g\in H$ and $H\trianglelefteq G\implies [g]_G\subset H$.

So you were successful.

It's just that the use of $h$ for an arbitrary element of $G$ is a little confusing.  (One might think that $h\in H$.)